# Showing that two given functions are harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm preparing for my complex analysis midterm on Thursday and our professor gave us the following as a practice problem:

[image]

I'm a bit confused on how to approach part (a). Here's my train of thought: showing that $1/f$ is analytic will show that $u/(u^2+v^2)$ and $v/(u^2+v^2)$ are harmonic, per a theorem in our textbook. However, I'm unsure as to how I'm supposed to show that $f$ is analytic. Should I try to make use of the Cauchy Riemann equations in some way? But what about points where $u^2 + v^2 = 0$? That leads to division by zero in the expression for $1/f$.

Comment: What does it mean that $v$ is a conjugate harmonic function to $u$?

Answer (score 1):

(a)   $1/f$ is analytic at every point where $f$ is not zero. Because $f$ is analytic. Because $v$ is the conjugate harmonic to $u$.

With (d), it's easier to guess. You can  recognize $x^2-y^2$ as the real part of $(x+iy)^2$, and $xy$ as $\frac12$ of its imaginary part. Generally: if it's a harmonic polynomial of degree $n$, then it somehow comes from $z^n$.

Comment: For part (c), could I just say consider the analytic function $\log(f) = \ln|f| + iArg(f)$ and say that since $\ln|f|$ is the real part of an analytic function, it is harmonic?

Comment: @RyanDavidson It boils does to what you know about complex logarithms. You know they are sort of multi-valued, right? But the real part of $\log z$ is just $\log|z|$. It comes from polar coordinates $z=re^{i\theta}$, for example.